# Setting DateTime to empty value c#

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

I am trying to set the date time to an empty value in my application - I am trying in the following way

```
    string datetime = Convert.ToString(dataRow["dbfield"]).Trim();
    MyDateTime= string.IsNullOrEmpty(datetime)
                    ? (DateTime?) null
                    : GeneralUtilities.ConvertOTDateToDate(datetime);
```

The error I am getting is

> cannot implicitly convert type System.Datetime? to System.Datetime, an
>   explicit conversion exists are you missing a cast?

Please could someone help me with the correct syntax required for this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume `MyDateTime` is declared as a `DateTime`.  Change it to `DateTime?`.

*or*

`GeneralUtilities.ConvertOTDateToDate` returns a `DateTime`.  Cast it to `DateTime?`.  As in:

```
MyDateTime= string.IsNullOrEmpty(datetime)
                ? (DateTime?) null
                : (DateTime?)GeneralUtilities.ConvertOTDateToDate(datetime);
```

Comment: second one is true, he's returning two different values

Comment: @wudzik No it's definitely the first one because you can implicitly convert `DateTime` to `DateTime?`.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: It is, but that's not related to OPs issue.  @juharr, it's hard to judge which it is, since the declaration of `MyDateTime` isn't provided, nor is the method signature to `GeneralUtilities.ConvertOTDateToDate`

Comment: @Amy, The message is about converting a `DateTime?` to a `DateTime`.  The result of the ternary operator will be a `DateTime?` becuase of the cast regardless of what the method returns.  Thus the variable is `DateTime`.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath The cast is only redundant if the method returns `DateTime?` if it returns `DateTime` then the cast will force the ternary return to be `DateTime?`.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime is a struct and thus cannot be null. Change it to a DateTime? if you want to use null. Alternatively use something like DateTime.MinValue as the default value.

Answer (score 0):

GeneralUtilities.ConvertOTDateToDate must return a nullable DateTime instead of a normal DateTime, probably.